# JavaScript - Adding a parameter to a success callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, reactjs, w3c-geolocation

Languages: Reactjs and vanilla JavaScript

The question is more of just a **general JavaScript callback question** but I'll add my React code to show how I ended up in this predicament.

Lets look,Tarantino style, at my confusing blunder:

**I'm trying to send a callback as a parameter of a success callback**

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success(dataLoaded), error, options);
```

but it didn't like because "pos" is suppose to be the "sole input parameter " for the success callback according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

Now lets rewind and figure out what got me into this mess:

I'm using a callback as a way of giving my React app the thumbs up that the asynchronous fetching is done and to render itself.

```
onDataLoaded: function() {
    this.setState({
        postsLoaded: true,
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    WebAPIUtils.fetchComponentData(this.onDataLoaded);
  },
render: function() {
    if(!this.state.postsLoaded){
        return (<div className="Loading">Loading...</div>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        //Components can be rendered now since their data is loaded. 
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Once the code below is successful I need to execute that callback:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
  //Here I want to execute my callback to render.
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

But geolocation.getCurrentPosition has [prescribed callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) and so it seems **there is  no way of passing that callback as a parameter of the success callback**

Is there a way to pass that callback as an extra parameter of the success callback? A callback being sent as a parameter of a callback seems weird but forming my original callback to also handle the location logic outside of the location module feels tacky too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)!

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  success.bind(null, dataLoaded), 
  error, 
  options);

//

function success(dataLoaded, pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
  dataLoaded();
}
```

This essentially creates a new version of a function where you can replace `this` and pre-fill arguments. So the callback being passed to `getCurrentPosition` is a single-parameter function that, when called, will become `pos` in your `success` function.

Comment: What a pimp solution!! Let me try it out! :)